XCB Error when trying to start AppImage program
Upgraded to 24.04 and now Soulseek (AppImage) won't run.
The program has been made executable, read + write access.
./[name of program] 

yields the following error message:
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin in "".
Available platform plugins are: xcb

Any ideas on how I can fix this?
Thanks.
